# Hibernate @OneToMany does not save foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having an issue saving a one to many relationship. It seems that it is saving the elements of the list on the table, but it does not save the foreign key in the proper table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_applications")
public class ApplicationEntity
{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "intAPI", referencedColumnName = "intCode")
    private ApiResourceEntity objApi;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<ApplicationRoleEntity> colApplicationRoles = new ArrayList<ApplicationRoleEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<URLEntity> colUrls = new ArrayList<URLEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<KeyCredentialEntity> colKeyCredentials = new ArrayList<KeyCredentialEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<PasswordCredentialEntity> colPasswordCredentials = new ArrayList<PasswordCredentialEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<RequiredResourceAccessEntity> colRequiredResourceAccess = new ArrayList<RequiredResourceAccessEntity>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_apiresources")
public class ApiResourceEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "intCode")
    private Integer intCode;
    private Integer intRequestedAccessTokenVersion;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "intCode")
    private List<PermissionScopeEntity> colOauth2PermissionsScope = new ArrayList<PermissionScopeEntity>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_permissionsscope")
public class PermissionScopeEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "intCode")
    private Integer intCode;
    private String strAdminConsentDescription;
    private String strAdminConsentDisplayName;
    private String strID;
    private Boolean bolIsEnabled;
    private String strOrigin;
    private String strType;
    private String strUserConsentDescription;
    private String strUserConsentDisplayName;
    private String strValue;
}
```

---

an example of what it saved on the database:

```
tbl_applications
intAPI = 1
tbl_apiresources
intCode = 1
intRequestAccessTokenVersion = 2
intOauth2PermissionScopes = NULL
tbl_permissionsscope
intCode = 1
strAdminConsentDescription = xxxxxx
strAdminConsentDisplayName = xxxxxx
strID = xxxxxx
bolIsEnabled = xxxxxx
strOrigin = xxxxxx
strType = xxxxxx
strUserConsentDescription = xxxxxx
strUserConsentDisplayName = xxxxxx
strValue = xxxxxx
```

it saves the elements of the list (Permissions Scope), however the foreign key is not save on the table tbl_apiresources. Maybe because the identifier is an Identity Field (Self Generated)

All the @OneToMany relationships of the ApplicationEntity Object are saved properly. @OneToMany can not point to @ManyToOne as I get a circular reference exception

Comment: could it be due to the fact you are initialising the List with     `private List<PermissionScopeEntity> colOauth2PermissionsScope = new ArrayList<PermissionScopeEntity>();`

Comment: Which fk is saved in the *wrong* table? If you mean the fk of the `List<PermissionScopeEntity>` how do you want to save a List of fk in a column?

Comment: the mappedBy attribute must point to a ManyToOne relationship

Comment: Mapped by must have a corresponding `ManyToOne` mapping, which specifies the foreign key column on the owning side of the relationship.

Comment: What do you mean with *@OneToMany can not point to @ManyToOne as I get a circular reference exception* , it is definitely possible to create a birectional relationship, please share code on how you tried to implement that

Answer (score 1):

When you specify only a `@OneToMany` relationship, i.e., unidirectional from Parent to Child, hibernate will implement the mapping with a join table. When you save a parent/child relation the keys are inserted into the join table:

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    Set<Child> children;
}
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
```

Results in the join table parent_child

```
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table child (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table parent (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table parent_children (parent_id bigint not null, children_id bigint not null, primary key (parent_id, children_id))
Hibernate: alter table parent_children add constraint UK_fh9rqlaf2416b31ec7n92nrfh unique (children_id)
Hibernate: alter table parent_children add constraint FK2li53iimvay1c1bjvc1hed3gl foreign key (children_id) references child
Hibernate: alter table parent_children add constraint FKdnxvj4hlnv40nix37bpjsvecn foreign key (parent_id) references parent
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into child (id) values (?)
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into parent (id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into parent_children (parent_id, children_id) values (?, ?)
```

If you want the FK to be in the child table, and you do, then define a unidirectional mapping from the child to the parent.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
}
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;   
    @ManyToOne
    Parent parent;
}
```

Which does not create a join table

```
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: create table child (id bigint not null, parent_id bigint, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table parent (id bigint not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table child add constraint FK7dag1cncltpyhoc2mbwka356h foreign key (parent_id) references parent
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into parent (id) values (?)
Hibernate: call next value for hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: insert into child (parent_id, id) values (?, ?)
```

If you want a bidirectional mapping than add both but understand that you should do persistence like the second example and use the parent `Set<Child> children` for queries only for performance reasons.

```
@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @OneToMany
    Set<Child> children;
}
@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    Parent parent;
}
```

After inserting, then query with `left outer join fetch` or better by using an `EntityGraph`.

```
"from Parent p left outer join fetch p.children where p.id = :id"
```

Comment: Hi: The following exception is displayed if I use the OneToMany on Parent and ManyToOne on Child. java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object circular reference on transient instance - circular reference on transient instance: azure.entities.PermissionScopeEntity

Comment: that exception has nothing to do with onetomany and manytoone, it just means that you have an entity in your transaction which hasn't been saved, make sure to save all entities or use cascading to save related entities, if you share the code you wrote that lead you to this exception I can help you

Answer (score 0):

Kindly find below the modifications that I made to the code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_applications")
public class ApplicationEntity
{
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "intAPI", referencedColumnName = "intCode")
    private ApiResourceEntity objApi;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<ApplicationRoleEntity> colApplicationRoles = new ArrayList<ApplicationRoleEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<URLEntity> colUrls = new ArrayList<URLEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<KeyCredentialEntity> colKeyCredentials = new ArrayList<KeyCredentialEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<PasswordCredentialEntity> colPasswordCredentials = new ArrayList<PasswordCredentialEntity>();
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "strApplication")
    List<RequiredResourceAccessEntity> colRequiredResourceAccess = new ArrayList<RequiredResourceAccessEntity>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_apiresources")
public class ApiResourceEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "intCode")
    private Integer intCode;
    private Integer intRequestedAccessTokenVersion;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "intCode")
    private List<PermissionScopeEntity> colOauth2PermissionsScope = new ArrayList<PermissionScopeEntity>();
}
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_permissionsscope")
public class PermissionScopeEntity
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "intCode")
    private Integer intCode;
    private String strAdminConsentDescription;
    private String strAdminConsentDisplayName;
    private String strID;
    private Boolean bolIsEnabled;
    private String strOrigin;
    private String strType;
    private String strUserConsentDescription;
    private String strUserConsentDisplayName;
    private String strValue;
    @ManyToOne
    private ApiResourceEntity objApi;
}
```

If I only let the annotation @OneToMany on the ApiResourceEntity I got the exception mentioned above

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object circular reference on transient instance - circular reference on transient instance: azure.entities.PermissionScopeEntity
```

When I add the cascade = CascadeType.ALL I got the following error:

> org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid column name
>   'objApi_intCode'.

with and without the mappedBy = "intCode"